# Laravel upload file outside root path

Tags: laravel, file, upload

I tried everything but cannot get a file upload to work.

I want it to upload to:

/var/www/mysite.com/uploads

Laravel is located at:

/var/www/mysite.com/admin/public/

Latest thing I tried was making a filesystem like this:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/var/www/mysite.com/uploads'
]
```

I also tried

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '../../uploads'
]
```

none of them did work.

Can anyone please tell me how I can upload files, outside of my Laravel directory to the directory I specified above?

EDIT: The error I receive:

League \ Flysystem \ Exception
Impossible to create the root directory "/var/www/mysite.com/uploads/image.jpg".

Also tried this:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/uploads'
]
```

with controller code:

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store(
    'image.jpg', 'uploads'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It should even be OS-agnostic:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => __DIR__ . '/../../uploads/'
]
```

Comment: Thought that base_path() returns the base path where Laravel is located so:

www.mysite.com/admin/ { laraven is here }

and I need to upload it to www.mysite.com/uploads/

so basicly 1 folder infront of Laravel's root :)

Comment: Nevermind, I read your question wrongly, I'll update my answer

Comment: Ill give that a try tonight and let you know the outcome :)
I beleve I already tried it without any luck though, but ill let you know! 

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Let me know! Just so you know, PHP probably won't create the uploads folder for you, so you might have to do that manually. (Which now I think of it, might be the problem in the first place, given the error message "Can't create root directory")

Comment: The folder exists ;) Ill post my directory structure et cetera as well tonight so you visually can see what I mean :)

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked! thanks so much haha. No clue what the difference is, cause both would point to the exact same directory but oh well... if it works it works! thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! Could you accept as an answer so other can benefit too?

Comment: In the end, this is what I had to do:

`$path = $request->file('image')->storeAs(
                '/', $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName(), 'uploads'
            );`P.S. How do I accept as an answer?

Comment: Glad you could find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem is solved in this way,
I've created a directory called `uploads` one level upper than laravel root directory.
after that in `config/filesystem.php` added this piece of code:

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('storage2') =>  __DIR__ . '/../../uploads',
    ],
```

and also,

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'public2' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => __DIR__ . '/../../uploads',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

    ],
```

and finally entered the `php artisan storage:link` in terminal.

---

Actually what it does is that in `public` directory, a directory named `storage2` is created and this directory will point to `uploads` folder that is created outside of laravel root directory.

please note that this lines of code create the `uploads` direcotry and after that all images will store in this location.

```
'public2' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => __DIR__ . '/../../uploads',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

---

for storing uploaded image in created `uploads` directory, I used this code:

```
        if ($request->hasFile('cover')) {

            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover')->getClientOriginalName ();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('cover')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;       

            $path = $request->file('cover')->storeAs('/image/blog', $fileNameToStore, 'public2');
        }
```

and for displaying this image (in blade file):

```
<td><img src="{{asset('/storage2/image/blog/' . $post->cover)}}" width="50" height="50"></td>
```